# Object obj = true; but Java says obj is Boolean

Tags: java

I am trying to understand something about the way java interpretes the type of an object.

Here is what I mean:

```
@Test
void checkObj() {
   // Output: INFO: Obj true is of type class java.lang.Boolean
   Object obj = true;
   log.info("Obj {} is of type {}", new Object[] {obj, obj.getClass()});
}
```

`obj` has been declared as of type `Object` and we know that `true` is of type `Boolean`, right? So when we assign `true` to `obj` why does `java` tell us that `obj` is of type `Boolean` instead of telling us that it is of type `Object`?

I've looked at the source code implementation for both `Boolean` and `Object`. `Object` is not an interface and `Boolean` does not extend or implement `Object` hence polymorphism is out of the question so where is the link between the two?

Source code of `Boolean` begins like so:

```
public final class Boolean implements Serializable, Comparable<Boolean> { // ...
```

Source code of `Object` begins like so:

```
public class Object { // ...
```

No direct link between `Object` and `Boolean` as far as the eye can tell.

Comment: `we know that true is of type Boolean, right? ` <- Not quite. `true` is of the primitive `boolean` type, and because you cannot assign a primitive to an object java then autoboxes that primitive in the `java.lang.Boolean` class. Also **Every java class extends `java.lang.Object` implicitly if it doesn't extend another class** so your statement that "Boolean does not extend or implement Object" is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where did you see `Boolean` does not extend `Object` ?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

First few lines of the definition:

`public final class Boolean extends Object implements Serializable, Comparable<Boolean>`

You are assigning a primitive boolean to Object which then autoboxes it into the Boolean object.